# SQL Inner join on select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I am trying to make an inner join on a select statement like this:

```
select *
from (select* from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab1
inner join (select * from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab2
on tab1.close=tab2.close
```

and I get the following error:
ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 56):

Just remove `as` from your query:

```
select *
from (select* from bars  where rownum <= 10 ) tab1
inner join (select * from bars  where rownum <= 10 ) tab2
on tab1.close=tab2.close
```

Comment: Hi egorius, thanks, it worked. I still don't understand why sometimes oracle accepts the as and sometimes not

Comment: 'As' can be (optionally) used before a COLUMN alias. TABLE aliases can't be prepended by 'as'. For example: "select count(*) as cnt from dual d".

Comment: You may want to have a look at SELECT syntax diagram (it's quite big, but defines exact syntax): http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_103a.htm#SQLRF01702

Comment: I had the same problem that "as" fails when it joins empty table. Without "as" it works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error comes from you needing a semicolon to end the statement.  The select looks fine to me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
((select* from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab1
inner join (select * from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab2
on tab1.close=tab2.close)
```

Answer (score 1):

just give a whitespace between ')' and 'as':

```
select * from (select* from bars  where rownum <= 10 ) as tab1
 inner join
 (select * from bars  where rownum <= 10 ) as tab2
 on
 tab1.close=tab2.close
```