# SQL Inner join on select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Inner join on select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940579/sql-inner-join-on-select-statements)

I am trying to make an inner join on a select statement like this:

```
select *
from (select* from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab1
inner join (select * from bars  where rownum <= 10 )as tab2
on tab1.close=tab2.close
```

and I get the following error:
ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you need to highlight your lines of SQL or other code, and then click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard, to properly and nicely format code sections - it helps a lot!

Comment: Why would you do something like this?

Comment: You've just asked the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940579/sql-inner-join-on-select-statements

Comment: This is the third post on this topic you have started.  It would be a lot easier for everybody if you just edited your original question with the additional information.

Comment: Hi marc, thank you for the tip I was wondering how to do it!
Egorius yes I asked the same question on another post I must have have done something wrong, it wasn't my intention :). I will edit it next time to make it easier for the readers

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a space between "select" and "*" in "select*".