# SQL simple selection of rows according to their time

Tags: sql

I have a table with  measures and the time this measures have been taken in the following form: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM. I have measures over many days starting at the same time every day.The datas are minute by minute so basically the seconds are always = 0. I want to select only the measures for the first 5 minutes of each day. I would have used the where statement but the condition would only be on the minutes and note the date is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: iracema, you should definitely go back and review the answers to your questions. This one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940579/sql-inner-join-on-select-statements
From your comments it looks like the solution worked for you but you never checked it as a solution. All you have to do is click on the gray checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE
DATEPART(hh, timestamp_col) = 0 AND -- filter for first hour of the day
DATEPART(mm, timestamp_col) <= 5 -- filter for the first five minutes
```

Careful! 0 means midnight. If your "first hour" of the day is actually 8 or 9 AM then you should replace the 0 with an 8 or 9.